# Displaying a tooltip when hovering over a tab with uib-tab?

Tags: javascript, html, css, angularjs, twitter-bootstrap

I'm having an HTML/Bootstrap issue. I have a group of tabs that I display using the uib-tabset directive on Angular Bootstrap (UI Bootstrap).  I want to display a tooltip that displays when hovering over the tab if the tab is disabled. Anyone have an idea how to do this? Here is the HTML (I'm not really sure what else to put, it's pretty simple):

```
<uib-tab disable="isBracketdisabled">
    <uib-tab-heading>
      I AM A HEADING
    </uib-tab-heading> 
</uib-tab>
```

If anyone could help I'd be very thankful. Thanks!

Answer (score 3):

Simply apply the `uib-tooltip` directive to your tab using the `tooltip-enable` option to only display the tooltip when your condition is met:

```
<uib-tab uib-tooltip="text" tooltip-enable="isBracketdisabled" 
    tooltip-class="customClass" disable="isBracketdisabled">
```

In regards to your comment, you can apply custom styling by using the `tooltip-class` attribute and passing in a custom class. You can then style it to your liking in your css:

```
.tooltip.customClass {
    z-index: 1000
}
```

Comment: Ha, wow. I was definitely overthinking this. Quick question, though, any idea how to adjust the css for the tooltip? I'm running into a z-index issue. Thank you!

Comment: @amacdonald that's a separate question, but I'm happy to answer it.  I've updated my answer.

Comment: You're welcome, very happy to help!  If you would be so kind, please consider marking my answer as accepted to help others down the road.